# Third person view camera with marmalade SDK

Tags: opengl-es, airplay, marmalade

Help me please to get camera following target point. I can't do it for 2 days already for the new prototype project in my company. Currently i have:

```
void Camera::followTargetPoint(CIwVec3 target, int32 distance, int32 height)
{
    CIwVec3 viewSpaceLocation = (CIwVec3)IwGxGetModelViewMatrix().TransformVec(target);
    IwTrace(SCOOTER, ("viewSpaceLocation: x: %d, y: %d, z: %d", viewSpaceLocation.x, viewSpaceLocation.y, viewSpaceLocation.z)); 
    // set the viewspace origin to the camera location in viewspace
    //IwGxSetViewSpaceOrg(&viewSpaceLocation);
    CIwVec3 pos = CIwVec3(viewSpaceLocation.x, viewMatrix.t.y, viewSpaceLocation.z);

    viewMatrix.SetTrans(pos);
    //viewMatrix.LookAt(CIwVec3(0,0,-100), target, CIwVec3(0,-100,0));

    IwGxSetViewMatrix(&viewMatrix); 


}
```

this method called in my renderer like:

```
p->Render();

    cam->followTargetPoint(p->getModelMatrix().GetTrans(), 3, 100);
```

What i need is a third person view camera that is located at a distance and height specified by followTargetPoint method. I can only get a first person view with this code cuz when i trying to subtract a distance from z coordinate of target vector i get a flickering model and i know the reason but the question i how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to know which direction your point is travelling in, in order to be able to follow it. Unless you can make assumptions about this, e.g. is it a top-down 2d game?

Anyway, given a direction, your camera position in world space would be something like:

```
CIwVec3 camPos = ( target - ( targetDirection * distance ) );
camPos.z += height; // assuming Z is up
```

You then need to build a matrix using this position, but you'll also need 3 axes. The forward axis is:

```
( target - camPos ).Normalized();
```

Then you can use some cross products assuming a rough up vector of 0,0,1, to construct the other 2 axes. You should be able to figure out/google for how to build that matrix given a point and a forward vector. I can't just spoon-feed you the whole thing ;)

Then you can set the inverse of your newly constructed matrix as your new view matrix:

```
viewMatrix = viewMatrix.Inverse();
IwGxSetViewMatrix(&viewMatrix);
```

Sorry I'm not familar with the IwGx API so I probably typed some function names incorrectly.